# How to split a list based on pattern

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I am trying to split a list based on pattern of some elements of the list.

```
list = {a^(-1-x1),b^(-x2), (a+b)^(-x3), (1-a)^(-1+x4),(1-b)^(-1), (1+a b)}
```

I want to split the list into two based on a pattern given as a list. I am using `SequenceCases` to achieve that. However it does not work for more than two patterns given as a list.

```
 pattern = {Power[a,x_],Power[b,y_],Power[1-a,z_]};
 list1=SequenceCases[list,pattern]
```

whose output (expected) should be

```
 list1={a^(-1-x1),b^(-x2), (1-a)^(-1+x4)}
 list2={(a+b)^(-x3),(1-b)^(-1), (1+a b)}
```

Note that I do not want to split the list based on position of elements, rather based on certain pattern/members of the list.

Additionally I wanted to ask if there is any easier way to find all the elements which have negative exponent (assuming all non-numeric variables in the exponent are `0`.).

```
 {a^(-1-x1), (1-a)^(-1+x4), (1-b)^(-1)}
```

I can perform a `Do` loop through the elements of the list, however it would be nice to know if there is any better alternative.

Comment: Might I recommend: `GroupBy[list, MatchQ[#, Alternatives @@ pattern] &]`

That groups into a `True` group that matches the pattern and a `False` group that does not. You can access via `result[True]` or `Lookup[result, True]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you *have to* use `SequenceCases` and `pattern`:

```
list1 = Flatten @ SequenceCases[list, {Alternatives @@ pattern}]
```

> ```
> {a^(-1 - x1), b^-x2, (1 - a)^(-1 + x4)}
> ```

```
list2 = Flatten @ SequenceCases[list, {Except[Alternatives @@ pattern]}]
```

> ```
> {(a + b)^-x3, 1/(1 - b), 1 + a b}
> ```

Otherwise, you can use `Cases`:

```
list1b = Cases[list, Alternatives @@ pattern]
```

> ```
> {a^(-1 - x1), b^-x2, (1 - a)^(-1 + x4)}
> ```

```
list2b = Cases[list, Except[Alternatives @@ pattern]]
```

> ```
> {(a + b)^-x3, 1/(1 - b), 1 + a b}
> ```

For both methods, we can use an alternative simpler pattern top get the same result:

```
pattern2 = Power[a | b | (1 - a), _];

Flatten @ SequenceCases[list, {pattern2}]

Cases[list, pattern2]

% == %% == list1
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
Flatten @ SequenceCases[list, {Except @ pattern2}]

Cases[list, Except @ pattern2]

% == %% == list2
```

> ```
> True
> ```

**"to find all the elements which have negative exponent (assuming all non-numeric variables in the exponent are 0.)."**

```
Cases[list, _^(a_ + _.) /; Negative[a /. _Symbol -> 0], All]
```

> ```
>  {a^(-1 - x1), (1 - a)^(-1 + x4), 1/(1 - b)}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
lst = {a^(-1 - x1), 
  b^(-x2), (a + b)^(-x3), (1 - a)^(-1 + x4), (1 - b)^(-1), (1 + a b)};


lst1 = lst /. Power[y_, x__] /; y == a || y == b || y == c -> Nothing
lst2 = Complement[lst, lst1]

(*  {(a + b)^-x3, (1 - a)^(-1 + x4), 1/(1 - b), 1 + a b}

{a^(-1 - x1), b^-x2}   *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

```
list = 
 {a^(-1 - x1), b^(-x2), (a + b)^(-x3), (1 - a)^(-1 + x4), 
 (1 - b)^(-1), (1 + a b)};

pattern = {Power[a, x_], Power[b, y_], Power[1 - a, z_]};
```

**1.**

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
Catenate @ SequenceSplit[list, {Except[Alternatives @@ pattern]}]
```

{a^(-1 - x1), b^(-x2), (1 - a)^(-1 + x4)}

**2.**

Using `Extract`

```
p = Position[list, Alternatives @@ pattern]
```

{{1}, {2}, {4}}

```
Extract[p] @ list
```

{a^(-1 - x1), b^(-x2), (1 - a)^(-1 + x4)}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {a^(-1 - x1), b^(-x2), (a + b)^(-x3), (1 - a)^(-1 + x4), (1 - b)^(-1), (1 + a  b)};

pattern = {Power[a, x_], Power[b, y_], Power[1 - a, z_]};
```

---

Using `DeleteCases`:

```
sp = {Except[Alternatives @@ pattern], Alternatives @@ pattern};

Map[DeleteCases[list, #] &, sp]

(*{{a^(-1 - x1), b^-x2, (1 - a)^(-1 + x4)}, {(a + b)^-x3, 1/(1 - b), 1 + a b}}*)
```